# Switch the Odd One Out #4 (Advanced)

Tags: pattern, odd-one-out

[image: OOO4]

Here is #4 in the series, the most advanced one I have created so far. What two figures (one in range a-i and the other in range 1-9) are the odd ones that should be switched to restore both patterns, and why?

*created by myself*

Comment: A spontaneous observation is that i) is misplaced and should be replaced by either 5 or 6. This conclusion is drawn from the count of the arrow types in each row.

Comment: Is my answer the right one?

Answer (score 1):

I think its

> to switch i and 5

because

> on the right side are only **9 types** of objects. And by assuming
>  that every object is shown at least twice, one can see that there are
>  **11 available objects** on the right side (The big circle with the small border and: the half-moon filled black).
>  
>  With that I recognized that on he left side is no **half-moon but a
>  box with one (i)** so it doesn't fit - it's odd. So I changed it with
>  a box on the right side which has only objects which are available on
>  the left side - and that's only **the one in the middle (5)** 
>  [image]

but it could also be

> e and 5

because

> The left picture just contains boxes with 7 object and the right picture has rows with each having boxes with 7,6,5 "objects in it" (but not the middle row). And I think that these boxes have to be switches because it would "fit better" to have only "7 objects"-boxes on the left and a 5-6-5 row on the right middle row - simple it would fit better. These are the most odd boxes.
>  [image]